# How to map composite id and many to one (multi column) with shared column

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, many-to-one, composite-primary-key

I have a problem with shared column between composite id and multi column many to one relation in large legacy database. I have simplified the problem into mapping below which reproduce the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="Alfa">    
    <composite-id name="AlfaId" class="AlfaCompositeId">
      <key-many-to-one name="Bravo" class="Bravo" column="BRAVO_ID" />
      <key-property name="CharlieId1" column="CHARLIE_ID1" />
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="C" class="Charlie">
      <column name="CHARLIE_ID1" />
      <column name="BRAVO_ID" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="CookieA" column="COOKIE_A" />
    </class>
  <class name="Bravo">
    <id name="BravoId" column="BRAVO_ID" />
    <property name="CookieB" column="COOKIE_B" />
  </class>
  <class name="Charlie">
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="CharlieId1" column="CHARLIE_ID1" />
      <key-many-to-one name="Bravo" class="Bravo" column="BRAVO_ID" /> <!-- Reused column !!! -->
    </composite-id>
    <property name="CookieC" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Trying to save Alfa entity will throw:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException (Message=Invalid index 3 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=3).
```

NHibernate is trying to add BRAVO_ID column value twice. Once for composite id and once for many to one FK.

**Any way how to change to mapping XML to tell NHibernate to ignore second mapping of 'BRAVO_ID' column?**

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: I found another work around which is to set update and insert to false: `<many-to-one name="C" class="Charlie" update="false" insert="false">`. But then the C property works only on select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mapped the same columns as CompositeId and as ManyToOne, just get rid of the compositeId

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="Alfa">    
    <composite-id>
      <key-many-to-one name="Charly" class="Charlie">
        <column name="CHARLIE_ID1" />
        <column name="BRAVO_ID" />
      </key-many-to-one>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="CookieA" column="COOKIE_A" />
  </class>

  <class name="Bravo">
    <id name="Id" column="BRAVO_ID" />
    <property name="CookieB" column="COOKIE_B" />
  </class>

  <class name="Charlie">
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="IdPart1" column="CHARLIE_ID1" />
      <key-many-to-one name="Bravo" class="Bravo" column="BRAVO_ID" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="CookieC" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and Access it through the Property

Bavo b = alfa.Charly.Bravo;

Comment: Only now I realize that I probably over simplified my real scenario. You are partially correct. It will fix issue with exception, but it will modify the schema of database as it will loose relation(FK constrain) between Alfa and Bravo.

Comment: if you only have a missing foreignkeyconstraint you could just add that as auxiliary object in the xml mapping to get it created with schemaexport.